# General improvement flag/link in Stack Overflow Documentation subsections

Tags: feature-request, flags, documentation

We have for subsections (apart from mod and rude/abusive) three types of flags:

- unclear
- very low quality
- not an example

But these flags do not really cover it all.

When I look at a specific subsection and see the *flag* button there, I expect to be able to suggest specific improvements to that specific subsection.

I **know**, in the flag options for the whole page there are "missing detail" and "missing examples". But I intuitively don't look there; and it also isn't clearly section specific.

#### Concrete example

On the arrays page of the PHP tag there is a subsection about concatenating and merging arrays. It (as of writing this) only provides an example about `array_merge()`.

I wanted to suggest that this section adds a mention about the `+` operator executed on arrays and the semantic differences between `+` and `array_merge()`.

I looked at that section. I was expecting one of two things intuitively; either a direct link "request improvement of this section" or something in the flags menu of this section. But I found nothing appropriate

#### Suggested solution

Either add an improvement request link (on the same place where on normal questions/answers would be the add a comment link) or alternatively add section specific flags for this.

Comment: I think the underlying problem here is that examples are not separate "things". They may look like it for editing and voting, but they actually aren't (which can be seen when editing different examples)

Comment: You even can flag them separately and they have their own edit history. They look fairly self-contained and thus you intuitively expect to also provide specific feedback for them. … In case this isn't intended, they should be reworked to look less self-contained; but I don't think this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, when I moused over the Flag icon and saw the "Suggest Improvement" tooltip language, I expected to be able to leave a comment to the author/experts who are maintaining the example.  Instead, there's just the normal flags, which function without exception as "Report Problem" and not "Suggest Improvement".  There's not even a way to leave a suggestion there (maybe there's a custom flag message in the flag-for-moderator group?).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the problem and the first solution, but not necessarily the "Concrete example".

Ideally (as I perceive the ideals of Documentation), there shouldn't be "sections" of examples within a topic. If you want there to be a section, it should just be a new topic. We can link them together if there is a need.

I do think the Improvement Request part of Docs needs some work, and I believe they did say they were working on something in [the last Documentation Update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335529/documentation-update-september-29th?cb=1) (the Improvement Request changes and Discussion parts).

Comment: Right, I'm looking forward to their next update :-)