# Documentation Update, September 29th

Tags: discussion, documentation

This is the fifth post in our series of regular (roughly <strike>fortnightly</strike> weekly) updates on the [Documentation Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation).  See also the [previous post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334404/documentation-update-september-12th) in the series.

### Shipped Changes

#### Reputation

As [announced elsewhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334551/documentation-reputation-update-is-live), Documentation's reputation system has been updated.  Lots of time since then has been spent on bug fixes, and we're still crushing a couple of outstanding ones.

#### Retract proposed changes from dashboard

[image: It's in the cog menu]

It is now possible to retract a proposed change (allowing edits to the draft) without revisiting the topic involved.

[A similar option is on its way to the review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335380/80572).

#### Topic Outline

The first parts of the Topic Outline have shipped.

[image]

Side-by-side view (where examples were displayed on the right) has been removed as part of this.

Topic Outline sizes itself at page load to keep other sidebar content visible if possible, so community bulletin (and related content, and eventually ads) aren't pushed too far down the page by its addition.

### Planned Changes

#### Review Audits

Audit tasks will start showing up in the Proposed Changes review queue in the next week or so.

Additionally, we're going to start consuming more history to trigger those audits, as well as restrict access to review (and potentially proposing changes in the first place). We're still analyzing various cases, so expect to hear more about these changes even after audits ship.

#### Discussion

We've started recruiting users for (very early, mockup based) testing of the previously announced discussion feature. If you're interested, hit up [Jon in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33151052#33151052).

Here's an updated mockup:

[image: Discussion v... 4?]

#### Focus section

Work has begun on the focus section, expect to see it in the coming week or so.

#### Improvement Request changes

We're going to be making some changes to Improvement Requests to clear up some confusion around them.

First, we're going to only allow a single active improvement request on a topic or example per type of request. Each active improvement request will allow comments for further discussion, elaboration, or concurrence.

[image: Improvement request display]

Second, the post-downvote prompt is being redesigned to make it clear that your downvote can have an improvement request attached.

[image: New downvote prompt]

Comment: Now to see how effective the review audits are!

Comment: If the outline is to replace the side-by-side view, it should probably be sticky so it’s always in view. See [this example](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sticky.html#example3) for what I’m thinking.

Comment: I think that the audits should take their material from changes rejected as copied content or factually incorrect information.

Comment: So "Make an Improvement Request" is essential in case of down vote, If so, its amazing.

Comment: This makes me sad :(

Comment: @ManojKumar How so?

Comment: @InzimamTariqIT Kinda. Right now, when you pick a reason for downvoting an example, we automatically create an improvement request that matches that reason. The idea here is to make that step more explicit since the current implementation has caused some confusion on a number of occasion.

Comment: Glad to see the draft editing bugfix, and the topic outline looks nice! I'm still hoping "dismiss" gets replaced with ["decline" or "reject"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332512/choose-a-different-word-besides-dismiss-for-getting-rid-of-improvement-requests#comment397178_332512) before Google starts indexing Documentation, but I suppose that's minor in the greater scheme of Doc's concerns.

Comment: Frankly I'm no longer interested. It has become union nr 2 no more.

Comment: What about multi-language examples?

Comment: [Wut?](http://imgur.com/CLmseiE.png)

Answer (score 15):

**Topic Outline**

Looking good, I like the side bar topic outline. As I use a smaller resolution screen (it is on a projector), the size issue before was problematic (lightly) but now with this iteration I can really tell an improvement. From a UX standpoint this helped me.

One small aspect that would be a nice addition would be to include the vote counts for examples in the side bar, similar to how related and linked counts are shown (except without the coloring to indicate accepted answer).

For example (from [Promises - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises/846/introduction#t=201609292013076700945)):

[image]

Here is a small userscript that can be used to see what this would look like as well

```
$('.topic-outline-example-link').each(function(){
 var id = $(this).data('example-id');
 var vote = $('.example[data-example-id='+id+']:first').find('.example-score.vote-count-post').text();
 var title = $('<span>').text(' '+$(this).text());
 $(this).empty().append($('<b>').text(vote)).append(title);
});
```

**Review Audits**

Review is an aspect of Documentation that has become a problem in my opinion. Audits may help, but as alluded to in your post here, perhaps there should be more barriers to accessing the review queue for Documentation (500?), or to even proposing changes at all.

- With regards to access to the queue, in my opinion the bar must be raised.
- With regards to proposing changes, it is a little harder to determine, but it seems to me that if a 1 reputation user is first using the site, they may not fully understand the scope and design of Documentation to properly use it even if they are experts in their field.

I am not sure where the balance should be though. Should it be that the barrier is lower for access to the queue, or for access to proposing changes, or perhaps they should have the same barrier? Unsure, I think it may make sense to have the barrier for proposing at 150 (just above the association bonus), and the review at 500 (standard for review queues).

It is nice to see that this is a source of concern for the team though, because it is an important aspect of quality control in Documentation.

Comment: That would help to understand the ordering too...

Comment: The ordering is broken anyway. There doesn't seem to be a real correlation between the number of up votes and the quality of the documentation. The documentation which was created soonest and has the most edits are the ones with the most up votes. Last time I looked there was loads of good documentation with 0 upvotes

Comment: @rdans - The masses haven't arrived yet.

Comment: *"they may not fully understand the scope and design of Documentation to properly use it even if they are experts in their field."* - I wonder about that. I am confused and dazed about Documentation and have no idea what I would feed this hungry monster - lurking on meta seems to only make that worse with all the walls of text that are being written about it. Maybe the 1-rep users who are not hindered by meta-overload actually have a chance to do it better :)

Comment: @Gimby - Of the things to wonder about, 1 rep users not understanding how to use SO features should not be one of them.

Comment: @TravisJ ..  *"The masses haven't arrived yet"* ... what makes you think they ever will?

Comment: @charlietfl - Google isn't allowed to index docs at the moment as the feature is still in beta.

Comment: @TravisJ yup..that will help when someone searches *"[languageName] hello world"*. Still seems to me that 90% of what's there is already documented in already indexed and trafficked resources

Comment: Documentation is essentially a Wiki. 100 rep is needed for editing a community wiki on Q&A, the same bar can be used here.